# How to authenticate my form using javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, authentication

there

i need to authenticate before request to the url, if i use XMLHTTPRequest, things go fine

```
var xmlHttp = ...//some code goes here
xmlHttp.Open('POST','http://www.somesite.com/',false,userID,password);
xmlHttp.Send(null);
```

But if i need to use a form, like below

```
>var objForm = eval(formString);
>objForm.target='demoFrame'; //where demoFrame is an iFrame in another page
>objForm.action='http://www.somesite.com/';
>objForm.username.value=userID;
>objForm.password.value=password;
>objForm.method='post';
>objForm.submit();
```

But seems that the objForm cannot use "username" & "password" as the input for authentication, since i keep receiving "authentication failed" message from the host site

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is `eval` in JavaScript so bad? Any user can run what ever JavaScript he wishes in a website anyway using FireBug or an equivalent

Comment: @CodeMonkey: `eval` can allow an attacker to run Javascript on someone else's compute (if he can modify the string being `eval`d).  It's also very slow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that the other site is using HTTP Basic authentication.

Set the `action` to `'http://' + userId + ':' + password + '@www.somesite.com/'`

Comment: i've just try, but failed with no luck

Comment: I am pretty sure that is not a) possible in many browsers b) clever since it shows the userid and password in the url

Comment: Or is it possible that i use XMLHTTPRequest to open a page in an iframe? If i have to use XMLHTTPRequest to authenticate...

Comment: @Leo: Depending on the site, that may be possible.  Try it.